Define timeshift snapshots directory to auto delete while rebooting or shutdowning
everyone. I am beginner in Linux and I am having an issue with Timeshift. I created a Python-script to create snapshots, keep some snapshots in the system, and delete the old ones. In the code there is only the part of defining the directory of snapshots:
#!usr/bin/python3
import os, sys, subprocess, json

def define_snapshots_dir() -> str:
    snapshots_dir_before = '/run/timeshift/'
    snapshots_dir_after = '/backup/timeshift/snapshots'

    random_number = os.listdir(snapshots_dir_before) # No dirs found
    return snapshots_dir_before + random_number[0] + snapshots_dir_after

def main() -> None:
    #create_snapshot()

    snapshots_dir = define_snapshots_dir()
    #snapshots = list_snapshots(snapshots_dir)
    #delete_snapshots(snapshots_dir, snapshots)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

And I created a service to call this script. Here's a unit-file of this service:
[Unit]
Description=Create a system snapshot using Timeshift before shutdown or reboot
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=shutdown.target reboot.target halt.target unmount.target
After=local-fs.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/timeshift-shutdown-snapshots.py

[Install]
WantedBy=shutdown.target reboot.target halt.target

If testing manually with:
sudo systemctl start timeshift-shutdown-snapshots.service

it works well, the directory is defined. But when I reboot/shutdown the system the directory cannot be found.
Initially, I tried to call this service without Before=unmout.target, considering that the problem is in this thing. But even before unmouting the file system this problem still exists.
I use Ubuntu 24.04, Python 3.12.3

does this article provide any helpful guidance>

Are you aware that timeshift will do this itself? You just have to run the wizard. Using that you set up the backup location, the frequency of backing up, the number of the different period backups to keep and any directory inclusions or exclusions. After that it will follow the schedule including deleting any backups that exceed the number specified.

@PonJar Found it. Thanks
